# Enityframework - ConcurrencyMode where clause

Tags: entity-framework-4

Reading up on the web I can set ConcurrencyMode=Fixed against a entity framework database field.

My understanding is that any update statements include in its where clause the original values to determine if the datacontext has changed.

(So if rows effected gets a hit then all is good otherwise we have a conflict )

Now my question is..

> Do only the columns changed in the
>   datacontext get included in the where
>   clause or **all** columns that are
>   marked as fixed.

i.e.
(If I have the following setup)

name=fixedconcurrency

DateofBith=fixedconcurrency

NI=fixedconcurrency

When only the name field changes would I get:

> update tbuser set name="newJason" 
>   where Id=2 and name="oldJason" and
>   DateofBith="19/10/1970" and NI=1234566

or

> Update tbuser set name="newJason" 
>   where Id=2 and name="oldJason"

My goal is to only have conflicts raised when a user overwrites another users data ( At field level not record level).

A snippet from MS says that entity framework will only update the fields that a user has edited. IF all fields are included in the where clause it would make this statement redundant.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Is this the way to go? https://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/08/24/using-self-tracking-entities-with-silverlight-4-and-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All of them. The intention of the feature is for something like a `TIMESTAMP` field, which the user cannot assign directly.